# NetBeans IDE issue adding grid layout

Tags: java, netbeans, grid-layout, sudoku

[image]   I have created a design of my application with net beans programme . I would like to add a 30*30 grid layout something similar to sudoku .Actually I am trying to draw a 30*30 of squares for map. However , I am not able to add that view to my code .I have searched lots of places but I am not able to find an answer .I am open to your ideas. Could anyone help me in this subject please ? Thank you !

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    getDirectionButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    questionTitle = new java.awt.Label();
    questionText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    directionDescriptionArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    walkingManButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    java.awt.Panel mapPanel = new java.awt.Panel();

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();


    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("DSL For Streets\n");
    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1365, 730));

    getDirectionButton.setText("Get Direction");

    questionTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 3, 12)); // NOI18N
    questionTitle.setText("Please enter your question");

    directionDescriptionArea.setColumns(20);
    directionDescriptionArea.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(directionDescriptionArea);

    walkingManButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 3, 11)); // NOI18N
    walkingManButton.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("walk.png"))); // NOI18N
    walkingManButton.setText("Get Suggested Route");
    walkingManButton.setFocusable(false);

    jButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("map.png"))); // NOI18N


    cells = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    tfCells = new JTextField[ROWS][COLS]; // allocate JTextField array

   // Container cp = getContentPane();
    //cp.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
mapPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
    // Create 9x9 JTextFields and place on the GridLayout
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
       for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
          tfCells[row][col] = new JTextField(); // allocate element of array
         mapPanel. add(tfCells[row][col]);  // ContentPane adds JTextField
          int number = puzzle[row][col];

          tfCells[row][col].setText("");  // empty
          tfCells[row][col].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
          tfCells[row][col].setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 20));
       }
    }

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mapPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mapPanel);
    mapPanel.setLayout(mapPanelLayout);
    mapPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mapPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mapPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(181, 181, 181)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 172, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(239, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(mapPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()

            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                .addComponent(getDirectionButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(questionTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 177, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(questionText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addComponent(walkingManButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 451, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(mapPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(46, 46, 46))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(questionTitle, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(questionText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(getDirectionButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                    .addComponent(walkingManButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 359, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addComponent(mapPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextArea directionDescriptionArea;
private javax.swing.JButton getDirectionButton;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField questionText;
private java.awt.Label questionTitle;
private javax.swing.JButton walkingManButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField a[]=new JTextField[30];
// End of variables declaration

public static final int ROWS = 9; // ROWS by COLS cells
public static final int COLS = 9;
public static final int CELL_SIZE = 10; // Cell width/height
public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = CELL_SIZE * COLS;
public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = CELL_SIZE * ROWS;
private int[][] cells;
private JTextField[][] tfCells;
private int[][] puzzle =new int[9][9];
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Netbeans, you can do that with the GUI Builder. Simply go to the Design View, right click on the underlying container you're going to use for this (some JPanel), go to "Set Layout" option in the context menu and pick "Grid Layout". To edit its properties, go to the Navigator window (usually on the left), browse your components until you see the container in question, collapse it and select the GridLayout. You can now change some properties, like the rows and columns, on the properties window (usually on the right). Then, you drag other components on top of that container.

Though, by your description, I wonder if what you're really looking for is a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), which is a component that lets you display your data in a grid.